# private interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, does interface always needs to be exported. I get error in the below case:

*error TS2019: Exported class 'Test' implements private interface 'ITest'.*

```
module xxx { 
    interface ITest {
    }

    export class Test implements ITest {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: export the interface too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case yes. You need to if you want to export the class that implements it:

```
module xxx { 
    export interface ITest {
        name: string
    }

    export class Test implements ITest {
       name = "ddsd"     
        constructor() {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can move ITest outside:

```
interface ITest {
    name: string
}

module xxx { 

    export class Test implements ITest {
       name = "ddsd"     
        constructor() {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```